# Undo a clone in pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have used git clone to clone a repository from GitHub. Now i have made some changes to that same repository, I want to clone it again, but Python anywhere has saved the earlier cloned repository and not allowing me to clone the updated one. Is there a way to undo/delete the earlier clone and copy the updated repository.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf cloned-repo` is one way.

most likely though, you maybe want to just do a `git pull`? Or a `git reset --hard` and then `git pull`?

ps: I would suggest reading up on how git works.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I am facing another error while going through the Django girls tutorial - Unable to login to django admin from pythonanywhere ,I had used the same superuser credentials and was able to access the Django admin through GitHub. error -"Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

Comment: through github? did you run createsuperuser again from a pythonanywhere console to create your admin use?

Comment: Unable to create, as I don't have root access there

Comment: You don't need root access to run the script to create a Django admin user.  You need to run the Django `python manage.py createsuperuser` script, as per the "Creating the database on PythonAnywhere" section of the Django Girls tutorial.